# Expression Tree: Modify operand using ExpressionVisitor

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm playing around with Expression trees in C# and would like to modify an expression.

I used this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) however in the example they reuse the left and right node. How would I go about modifying either of the nodes?

I got the following code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ExpressionDemo_ModifiesExpression()
    {
        var demo = new ExpressionDemo();

        var expression = demo.ModifyAddition((Expression<Func<int, int>>)(x => x + 1));
    }
```

I call ModifyAddition using a simple + 1 addition Func. I would like to modify the right operand (1) to a different integer.

```
public class ExpressionDemo : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression<Func<int, int>> ModifyAddition(Expression func)
    {
        return (Expression<Func<int, int>>) Visit(func);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Add)
        {
            Expression left = node.Left;

            Expression right = ???

            return Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, left, right);
        }

        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }
}
```

I'm confused as how to construct the proper right operand so I can return a new BinaryExpression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you *just* want to turn any `x + y` into `x + 1`? If so, I suspect you just want:

```
Expression right = Expression.Constant(1);
```

(You should validate that the addition type is for integers, of course.)

If that's *not* what you're trying to do, please be more specific.

Comment: I wanted to change x + 1 into x + 2 (as a test) and using Expression.Constant was exactly it. Thanks!